# WP Sidebar jQuery Toggle is not working

Tags: jquery

jQuery toggle in the right sidebar on my website stops working as soon as I take the script src code. It should be still working since jquery is being loaded by other plugins that are installed on my website but it is not.

website link: http://goo.gl/XuanJ

Toggle opens up when you click make a reservation.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a.res-toggle').click(function() {
      $('#reservation-box').toggle(400);
      return false;
   );
});
</script>
```

if I keep this code

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then slider on my website is not working right, because it's trying to import latest jquery and they crash I guess.

Comment: I've had issues where loading the jQuery library more than once will break the page. I don't now if that always happens, but maybe try having only one instance?

Comment: in that case the sidebar one does not work..

Comment: Considering that Wordpress loads jQuery in no-conflict mode, you should be using `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ...` and **then** your script will work without having to load jQuery twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution would be to move this code block into a seperate file say togglefunctionality.js and put it in your /wp-includes/js/jquery/ directory land then call it like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#side-res-open").click(function() {
 $('#reservation-box').toggle(400);
     return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

If you still see some conflict, and want to have this on the page only. then replace `$` with `jQuery` and you should be home.

Answer (score 0):

first of all - don't use additional jquery include

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then, use jquery in no conflict mode:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/